# reputation points - how are they determined and by whom?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

How and by whom are reputation points given?  On May 30 I answered a post and it was rated +30. On May 31 it was rated +25 (I don't know if that was a replacement or an addition).  On June 2 I received a rating of -10.  I received no explanation of any of this.  What is going on?

Comment: A full analysis on reputation is here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work. Basically reputation is only given in preset amounts, e.g. $+10$ for an upvote, but it of course stacks, so $5$ upvotes would total to $50$ rep gained for example

Comment: When you are displaying [your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), make sure that the checkbox for "show removed posts" is checked.

Comment: My opinion is that it is many times somewhat whimsical. I've seen well-thought-out posts that obviously involved a lot of effort and provided detailed, accurate analysis get 1 vote, and I've seen abjectly trivial answers (from members with 200k+ points) get 10x that. It's like facebook likes. You just can't take them too seriously.

Answer (score 4):

Everytime one person upvotes an answer, whoever answered gets 10 points. If a question is upvoted instead, whoever asked gets 5 points. If a question or answer gets downvoted, whoever posted it loses 2 points. If it was an answer being downvoted, whoever downvoted also loses 1 point. If a question gets accepted (with a green checkmark), who answered gets 15 points and whoever accepted the question gets 2 points.

Upvotes and downvotes may be retracted after the post has undergone an edit. If an account gets deactivated, all reputation changes caused by said account are voided (e.g., if someone upvoted one of your answers and they deactivate their account, you will lose 10 points).

It is not an arbitrary system that awards or take away points - everything is just feedback from the community.

Comment: None of the comments or the answer, including the information on the link, explain the -10 on June 2.  Is this a case where a +10 was removed?

Comment: Probably. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Click *Time* or *Post* in the reputation tab on your [profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/501262/herb-steinberg?tab=reputation&sort=time). You see that you lost 15 points on June 2nd, because an answer of yours was *unaccepted*. Earlier an asker felt that your answer settled their question. Apparently they now think that another answer is even better. Consequently you lost the 15 points that were given to you. The system allows only one accepted answer per question.

Comment: "Post" and "Time" are just sorting options on that tab. The third option "Graph" displays your rep changes differently. Click it to see.