# points for answers

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I recently answered a question and the answer was awarded $35$ points.  A few days later $15$ points were deducted.  What sort of mechanism determines the number of points in the first place and where did the subsequent deduction come from?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation It sounds like your answer was voted up twice (+10 points each) then accepted (+15 points), then unaccepted (-15 points), probably due to another answer that better addresses the asker's question.

Comment: You can check your reputation changes [on your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). (For example, today you can see there -15 with unaccept.) See also: [reputation points - how are they determined and by whom?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30346)

Comment: @MartinSleziak The question you linked to was asked by the same user!

Answer (score 8):

The questioner had accepted your answer, giving you +15 (in addition to the 2 time +10 from the two upvotes).

Yet, they then unaccepted your answer to accept another one. This deducted the +15.